# Redirect to subfolder invisibly htaccess PHP Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

my Website structure is as below:

```
root
 |
 |----- .htaccess
 |----- public
          |
          |----- index.php (has all Autoload classes)
 |----- application
          | ---- controllers
          | ---- models etc
```

Now you may have noticed that i have no `index.php/.html` in my Root directory and i deliberately did that because i want server to redirect by `.htaccess`.

I want to achieve that if you as a user visit website say:

```
http://localhost/testRedirect then it shall point to `public` folder
```

in the directory without showing `public` in the URL.

I tried blow solution from SO which claims to work like as i want:

**Solution 1** [this simply show Directory structure :( ]

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost\$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost\$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public [L]
```

**Solution 2** [Gives 404 :( ]

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ /public/
```

**Solution 3** [it redirects but shows `public` in the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost\$
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/testRedirect/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ public [L]
```

Please suggest some nice and working htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gags,

To do this, when running your server, set the document root to the `/public` folder.

**If you are using apache**, place this in the virtual host of the website settings.

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/project/public"
```

Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

**If you are using nginx**, Place the following in the `server{}` of the website settings.

```
root /path/to/project/public;
```

Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/

**For cPanel, Do the following**

- Log into cPanel.
- In the "Domains" section, click the Addon Domains or Subdomains icon, depending on which you'd like to modify.
- In the Modify a Domain section at the bottom of the page, click the  icon next to the current document root for the domain you wish to modify.
- In the popup window, enter the new document root and click Change.

Per the original posters details.  BigRock has a tutorial at https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/613/9/adding-an-additional-domain-to-your-multi-domain-linux-hosting

Comment: But if i am using cPanel then how can i change virtualhost file. If this can be done then this will be super cool

Comment: But why i will use addon domain or subdomain. Because i want to do it on original domain. Moreover i can not see any current document root which i can edit

Comment: What host are you on?

Comment: I am on bigrock host

Comment: https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/613/9/adding-an-additional-domain-to-your-multi-domain-linux-hosting

Comment: Noo. But for this i shal have multidomain host package and now i can not change for a year. And why addon domain. I want it only when when someone visits original url

Comment: This is the way to do it to set the document root through cPanel for a domain.  If you have questions, I would say contact your hosting provider as they will be able to help you.

Comment: And nog possible through htaccess?